# Sort a two dimensional String array with Arrays.sort based on a chosen column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a two dimensional array filled with strings in Java. I want to be able to sort the entire array relative to the column I have chosen to sort by.

**For Example:**

Say I have an Array of data that looks like this.

```
|John  | C | Doe    |

|Sally | A | Miller |

|Chris | B | Sanders|
```

I specify that I want to sort in descending order based on their middle initial and am returned an array that looks like this.

```
|John  | C | Doe    |

|Chris | B | Sanders|

|Sally | A | Miller |
```

Is there a way to designate a Comparator that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just pass the column index in as a parameter of the comparator.

```
class ColumnComparator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparator<T[]> {
  private final int column;

  ColumnComparator(int column) { this.column = column; }

  @Override public int compare(T[] a, T[] b) {
    return a[column].compareTo(b[column]);
  }
}
```

or, more simply, if it is always column 1 and string arrays:

```
class ColumnComparator implements Comparator<String[]> {
  @Override public int compare(T[] a, T[] b) {
    return a[1].compareTo(b[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Another quick question. Would this still work in a Java 6 implementation?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. Generics came in Java 5; Comparator and Comparable were both in Java 1.2.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and informative response :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] array = {{"John", "C", "Doe"}, {"Sally", "A", "Miller"}, {"Chris", "B", "Sanders"}};
        Arrays.sort(array, new IndexComparator(0));
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class IndexComparator implements Comparator {
    private int index = 0;

    public IndexComparator(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }


    @Override
    public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
        return o1[index].compareTo(o2[index]);
    }
}
```